# Which tags for questions on texts?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Right now we have the following tags that are related to buddhist texts.

- [pali-canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pali-canon) x  13
- [sutras](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sutras) x 9
- [texts](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texts) x 8
- [scripture](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) x 2
- [canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canon) x 2
- [buddhist-text](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buddhist-text) x 1

Most seem rather redundant to me, but which tags should we mark as synonym?

Personally I'm in favor of keeping [pali-canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pali-canon)  for questions about the pali canon in general and [sutras](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sutras) for questions about specific buddhist texts. We can mark [texts](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texts), [scripture](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) and [buddhist-text](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buddhist-text) as synonym of sutras. The one tag I'm not sure what to do with is [canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canon)

Answer (score 3):

Great suggestion! I would make [canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canon) a synonym of [pali-canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pali-canon) (is there any other canon in Buddhism?)

Not all texts belong to either [pali-canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pali-canon) or [sutras](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sutras) though, even in Theravada e.g. Milinda-panha, Visuddhimagga. Plus, there are Mahayana & Vajrayana texts that are not sutras.

One approach is to standardize on [texts](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texts) as the most encompassing tag, to be accompanied by another tag specifying a school e.g.

- [early-buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/early-buddhism) [texts](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texts)
- [theravada](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theravada) [texts](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texts)
- [mahayana](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahayana) [texts](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texts)
- [tibetan-buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tibetan-buddhism) [texts](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texts)

Comment: Interesting point about the pali canon being the only canon. I'm not sure if that's true (sorry) so I have asked the question on the main site http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2428/157

Comment: I don't have any personal knowledge of this but this answer indicates a Chinese canon: http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/what-are-the-canonical-texts-for-the-buddhisms-of-the-world/1760#1760

Comment: Yes, i suppose my point re:canon is arguable (although both Kanjur and Chinese body of Buddhist literature both being fuzzy / open-ended collections they are hardly canons in strict Western sense of the word) -- but practically speaking i don't expect many people to routinely tag or search for Kanjur / Chinese texts using the "canon" tag. Heck, i dont really expect more than a handful questions on these.

Comment: It might be more efficient for someone to be able to (for example) hit a tag of "tibetan-buddhism texts" than "tibetan-buddhism" and "texts" to zero in on the particular texts they were seeking without having to sort through all things marked "texts".